# ¿Cómo sugerir una mejor traducción de la UI?

Tags: soporte, faq, traducciones

He leido algunas oraciones que simplemente suenan extrañas o confusas en español, como:

> ¡Esta cola de revisión se ha desactivado!

Esta te da la idea de que se ha desactivado algo (no es cierto), si tomamos la traducción del inglés seria algo como:

> ¡No existen más elementos para revisar en esta cola!

¿Cómo se podrian sujerir mejores traducciones para la interfaz?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4):

Las sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones de la interfaz de usuario del sitio, así como los avisos de textos que no están traducidos, se pueden publicar como respuestas a esta pregunta: [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones)