# Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones

Tags: bug, traducciones

Si alguien encuentra algún texto que está traducido incorrectamente del original en inglés, o que podría beneficiarse de una traducción mejor, por favor escribir una respuesta a esta pregunta indicando:

- Dónde aparece el texto, a ser posible con una captura de pantalla
- Cuál es el texto incorrecto
- Cuál es la mejora propuesta

Atención: sólo para textos ya traducidos. Si lo que se encuentra es un texto que sigue en inglés, ver [esta otra pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/que-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos).

**IMPORTANTE:** Desde que se marcan las respuestas con [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) hasta que el cambio es realmente visible puede pasar un tiempo (minutos, horas en el peor caso) dado que tras cambiar los textos hay que esperar a que alguien lance una compilación del código para que los cambios se apliquen.

Comment: Donde podemos discutir cual sería la mejor traducción para algún término? veo por ejemplo que mucho utilizan `defecto` para traducir `default` cuando debería ser `por omisión`.

Comment: Para discutir, lo que procede es publicar una pregunta en meta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:discusión]. Como con cualquier pregunta, lo primero que hay que hacer es buscar si no hay ya un hilo sobre lo mismo.

Answer (score 5):

En las [elecciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1), al intentar retirarse **de las elecciones primarias**:

Aparece un mensaje:

```
&#191;Est&#225;s seguro de que deseas retirarte de esta elecci&#243;n?
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
¿Estás seguro de que deseas retirarte de esta elección?
```

[image: Retirarse]

Sin embargo, no aparece el mismo cartel si intento retirarme de **la postulación**.

En esta ocasión, sale codificado correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los códigos html son correctos:&#191;
&#225; y &#243; pero no están siendo codificados.

Answer (score 4):

Al votar para cerrar una pregunta propia (de la que soy el autor), el diálogo de confirmación muestra algunas entidades HTML que no está decodificando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reportado en MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/289691

Answer (score 3):

[estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o)

Hace unos momentos edité una pregunta y me salió en el mensaje `revisada por pares` no se si es por mi region pero no me parece que vaya bien la traducción ahi, podría ser `revisada por los editores` no se a modo de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En la sección `Medallas`

en `Erudito` debería ser `pregunta` sin la `r` al final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En el apartado de [¿Por qué veo un mensaje mencionando que mi pregunta no cumple con los estándares de calidad?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

El cuarto punto está escrito totalmente en inglés:

[image: bug]

Comment: Aunque, la verdad no es necesario, puesto que es lo mismo que dice el tercer punto

Comment: @Mariano pues parece que se perdió la traducción :/

Comment: @Mariano en ese caso ¿debería eliminarse completamente ese punto en inglés? Si se traduce debería quedar exactamente como el punto anterior. O ¿sería complicado eliminarlo?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez eliminado ;-) Tenías razón... y estábamos buscando en el lugar equivocado.

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando no has editado tu información de perfil, en la web mobile dice *`about me`* y debería decir *`acerca de mí`*.

Les dejo la imagen:

[image: imagen]

Comment: Buen aporte. Aunque una imagen dice más que mil palabras, sería bueno mencionar que se trata de la UI para dispositivos móviles.

Comment: La cadena se encuentra en Transifex con traducción aprobada. Se envió la sugerencia y se agregó un *comment-issue*

Comment: Si lo siento eso se me olvido mencionarlo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

[estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o)

### Preguntas sin responder pero con respuestas

Según se explica en [Qué es "Sin Responder"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1741/29967):

> ... Una pregunta está "sin responder" cuando está abierta, no tiene respuestas **o, si tiene respuestas, ninguna fue aceptada y ninguna tiene un puntaje positivo**.
>
> *preguntas que no tienen votos a favor ni respuestas aceptadas*

Considero que es un error terminológico que podría venir de SO en inglés, pero que en castellano es muy fácil de resolver. En mi caso, existía una confusión cuando entraba a [preguntas sin responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers), pues pensaba que allí estaban **todas** la preguntas **sin ninguna respuesta**. Pero resulta que sí hay preguntas con respuesta, lo que no hay es una **respuesta aceptada**. O sea, se trata de preguntas **sin resolver** o **sin aceptar**.

#### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Dejo aquí una traducción rápida de este problema [planteando en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/), y no estoy de acuerdo que en castellano se use la misma terminología, la cual es según mi opinión, confusa:

> Proporcionamos una facilidad para que la persona que hizo la pregunta marque una respuesta como una respuesta "aceptada". Una vez aceptada, la respuesta se etiqueta con una marca de verificación y un color de fondo especial, y permanentemente acoplada al fondo de la pregunta. Esta es una simple convención social que utilizamos para cerrar el lazo entre la persona que pregunta y la persona que responde - con un poco de reputación de azúcar para endulzar el trato (+15 a la respuesta, y +2 al propietario). Aceptar una respuesta no pretende ser una declaración definitiva y final que indique que la pregunta ha sido respondida perfectamente. Heck, ni siquiera esperamos que la gente que hace preguntas para volver y aceptar una respuesta la mayor parte del tiempo.
>
> Sólo entre tú y yo, no todos los interrogadores de preguntas están equipados para reconocer la mejor respuesta a su pregunta de todos modos - ahí es donde entra en juego el voto de la comunidad. Por eso en la orden de clasificación por defecto (votos), la respuesta de la comunidad será:
>
> 1. Directamente bajo la pregunta
> 2. Directamente bajo la respuesta aceptada, si hay una respuesta aceptada
>
> Así funciona Stack Overflow: las cosas buenas se votan en la parte superior, por lo que nunca tendrá que leer muy lejos para obtener la mejor información. Y en su mayor parte, funciona!
>
> Sin embargo, todavía necesitamos una manera de llegar a las preguntas que, por cualquier razón, no están siendo contestadas. Inicialmente nuestra vista de preguntas sin respuesta incluía preguntas con cero respuestas publicadas.
>
> Eso no funcionó muy bien, ya que algunas preguntas podrían tener varias respuestas publicadas que no eran ... satisfactorias. Desaparecerían del punto de vista de las preguntas sin respuesta, pero estas preguntas no eran realmente "respondidas" en ningún sentido real.
>
> Algunas personas propusieron mostrar todas las preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas, pero eso está contorsionando una simple convención social en mucho más de lo que se suponía que era. Esperar que cada asker regrese y marque una respuesta aceptada es totalmente irreal. Habría decenas de miles.
>
> A partir de hoy, he aquí cómo lo hacemos:
>
> - Las **preguntas contestadas** tienen al menos una respuesta con un upvote (o aceptado)
> - Las **preguntas sin respuesta** no tienen respuestas con upvotes (o aceptadas)
>
> Se han propuesto soluciones más complejas. Podríamos potencialmente ajustar el número de upvotes necesarios para que esto funcione - pero estoy pensando que esta es una manera mucho mejor de medir "respondido" que la forma en que solíamos hacerlo.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, en inglés se llama también así: _unanswered_.

Comment: "*lo que no hay es una **respuesta aceptada***" <-- Eso es incorrecto... Lo que no hay es una respuesta valorada (ya sea aceptada o votada), y no fue cerrada la pregunta.. Creo que no sería coherente alejarnos de la terminología usada en todo SE.

Comment: @fedorqui No sé lo que entiendan los ingleses por _unanswered_ pero sí sé que en castellano una pregunta con respuesta (correcta o no, valorada o no) es eso, una pregunta con respuesta.

Comment: @Mariano es medianamente incorrecto. Lo que sí es incorrecto es decir que una pregunta con alguna respuesta (correcta o no) es una pregunta sin respuesta. Entonces ¿cómo se llamaría a eso que en SO llamamos **respuesta**? Si ves la imagen arriba dice sin responder y abajo dice 1 respuesta. Hay un error de terminología y de incoherencia grave. PD: Lo de la pregunta cerrada no lo entendí.

Comment: De hecho, [ahora que lo miro](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=unanswered), puede que tengas razón. La traducción de _unanswered_ puede ser tanto _sin solución_ como _sin contestar_ o _sin respuesta_. Probablemente la primera podría ser más apropiada. Y al parecer [hace un tiempo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187704/209901) así se mostraba.

Comment: @A.Cedano SE no la llama "sin respuesta".. "Sin respuesta" es eso, que nadie publicó una respuesta... En cambio, SE la llama "no respondida" ... En esta publicación se explica el motivo detrás de definir así cuándo una pregunta se considera "respondida" o no: https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/  (una pregunta cerrada también se considera respondida, y en el blog también lo explica)

Comment: @Mariano Estamos hablando en **castellano**. Y estoy seguro de que la incoherencia viene de una _herencia_ que debe haber en inglés con el término _unanswered_. Yo en la imagen veo dos cuadros rojos, en uno dice **Preguntas sin responder** y en el otro dice **1 respuesta**. Si se llama **respuesta** a que se hizo una pregunta y uno **respondió** _"Hola"_, no podemos decir que es una **pregunta sin responder**. Y si se quiere decir que una respuesta no válida o poco votada no es una respuesta, también podríamos decir que ciertas preguntas **tampoco** llegan a la categoría de **pregunta**.

Comment: @fedorqui y, si bien se empezó a llamar "*need answers*" en el barra de navegación nueva, sigue apareciendo como "*unanswered*" en [diferentes partes de la interfaz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NlIi.png)

Comment: @A.Cedano Me perdí un poco con la última parte de tu comentario, pero creo que se malinterpretó mi punto. Creo que perfectamente podemos buscar un mejor término **en castellano** (incluso no es una *mala herencia* del inglés, ya que también generó el mismo problema). Pero no creo que "sin resolver" o "sin aceptar" sean una buena propuesta (aunque lamentablemente yo no tengo un mejor término)... Además, me pareció que en tu publicación se mezclaban los conceptos que ya están definidos en SE.

Comment: @Mariano Quiero decir que se está aplicando cierto _subjetivismo_ para **definir** lo que es o no es una **respuesta**. Una respuesta según esa definición es algo _que ha sido aceptado o que tiene algún voto positivo_. Si no ha ocurrido ni una cosa ni otra, según esa definición subjetiva, **no se considera respuesta**, pero eso sí, se le sigue llamando **respuesta**, como podemos ver en el segundo cuadro resaltado en la imagen: **1 respuesta**. Si aplicamos el mismo _subjetivismo_ para las preguntas, si las definimos por su calidad, entonces muchas no podrían ser llamadas preguntas.

Comment: @A.Cedano En ese comentario, en cada lugar que usaste "respuesta", debería ser "respondida": "no está respondida", o "no se considera respondida"... Esto es lo que vengo marcando. son preguntas que tienen respuestas pero aún no fueron respondidas; visto como respuestas que no respondieron a la pregunta.

Comment: Probablemente sería más interesante abrir una publicación aparte para comentar todo esto. Podrían surgir respuestas con ideas de cómo nombrar estos conceptos, que a su vez contarían con la zona de comentarios para mejorarlas.

Comment: @Mariano Lo que pasa es que en castellano, según yo, algo **respondido** es algo que **tiene al menos 1 respuesta**. El que esa respuesta **resuelva** o no el problema es otra cosa y en esa segunda parte entramos en el terreno de lo subjetivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo, pero a falta de un mejor termino, no tengo mejor forma de decirlo... No creo que estén "resueltas", no es un término que creo que lo describa con precisión y, en todo caso, copiar del inglés el término "necesita respuestas" lo veo más cercano... Me encantaría poder definirlo mejor y encontrar la forma de acordar en este punto, pero prefiero el "respondidas" feo y un poco absurdo (pero tan subjetivo como cualquier otro) que las alternativas propuestas hasta ahora... Acuerdo con fedorqui que convendría llevarlo al resto y dejar de hacerle ping a Konamiman

Comment: @Mariano Estoy de acuerdo en plantear el asunto en otra pregunta de Meta. ¿Tengo que plantearla yo?

Comment: Sí, hazlo tú mismo A. Cedano.

Comment: @A.Cedano Nadie está obligado a hacer nada. Por lo personal, yo hasta ahora estoy más inclinado a dejar todo como está... toledano también comentó algo similar a lo tuyo (https://gist.github.com/jstoledano/71273dc091aac897092b451eac805f3e) ... Si te da ganas, genial, sino quedará para quien quiera/pueda plantearlo

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En relación a [2017 Elección Moderador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1) en la sala de chat sobre las elecciones se publicaron varias observaciones y propuestas de mejora de traducciones y se creó un "bookmark", he aquí:

- [Observaciones página de elecciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61769/conversation/observaciones-pagina-de-elecciones)
- [Traducción de *freely*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61769/conversation/traduccion-de-freely)

Comment: Un poco después hablé yo de usar _libremente_ en lugar de _gratuitamente_.

Comment: @fedorqui: Agregué un bookmark y el enlace a este sobre lo de *freely*

Comment: Qué eficiencia, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

El botón para sugerir una nueva wiki de etiqueta no está traducido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes agregar tu sugerencia de traducción en [es.traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/), todo el proceso sobre traducciones aqui: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3166/65107

Answer (score -2):

Cuando en la cola de revisión le das al botón de "Eliminación recomendada" aparecen varias opciones entre las que a mí, personalmente, me choca mucho esta:

**Esto es comentario sobre otra publicación, no una respuesta**

Ante la duda, he ido a la versión inglesa y, si hacemos una traducción literal, realmente indica eso.

Sin embargo, creo que difiere bastante de la descripción que se da para este tipo de eliminación recomendada, ya que en la descripción habla de la pregunta propia (en la que se encuentra la respuesta a eliminar) y en el título habla de **otra publicación**. De hecho, a mí más de una vez me ha hecho dudar sobre que opción tenía que elegir a la hora de marcar una respuesta como `Eliminación recomendada`.

Pienso que una traducción posible podría ser esta:

**Esto es un comentario sobre la pregunta, no una respuesta**

que iría mucho más acorde a la descripción que se da de ella.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El tema de este texto es que también sirve para cuando alguien quiere dejarle un comentario a **otro** que **respondió**. Por ejemplo, "*Buena respuesta, pero deberías modificar...*"... Es decir, el mismo motivo sirve para respuestas que deberían haber sido comentarios en la pregunta **o** en una de las respuestas... Y, tener el mismo motivo para ambos también sirve a la hora de generar estadísticas de eliminación (agrupando a ambos casos dentro del mismo motivo)

Comment: @Mariano Pero en la descripción solo habla de la pregunta, no de ninguna de las respuestas. Por eso creo que no hay coherencia entre título/descripción.

Comment: Según lo entiendo yo, menciona a ambos: *no es una respuesta a la pregunta*, y *deja un comentario debajo de su publicación*. O sea, **(1)** no es una respuesta a la pregunta (ese es el problema, que no está *respondiendo*), y **(2)** debería ser un comentario en una publicación (es la solución, que debería haber *comentado debajo de otra publicación*)... Veo tu punto, que puede no ser lo más claro, pero me parece que cambiarlo a `pregunta` estaría mal, porque no necesariamente debería ser un comentario en la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano La verdad que no veo por ningún lado la alusión a las respuestas. Entiendo lo que quieres decir, igual debería ponerlo, pero actualmente creo que para nada está refiriéndose a ese punto. Ya que analizando mas detenidamente: **Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta** habla claramente de la pregunta. Yo creo que habla de la pregunta porque habla de `... pedir aclaración a un autor` se entiende que es de la pregunta, ya que no ha hecho antes referencia antes a ninguna respuesta. Es mi opinión que puede estar equivocada pero yo me he parado a pensar varias veces por esto.

Comment: "otra publicación" se refiere a cualquier post del hilo, ya sea la pregunta o bien una respuesta. La traducción que propones no considera que la respuesta a eliminar sea un comentario a otra respuesta del hilo. Yo considero que así como está, está bien.

Comment: @Rubén En el resto de comentarios le explico a `Mariano` el porque pienso que se refiere solo a la pregunta. Puedo estar equivocado, pero aún así, creo que habría que darle una vuelta en caso de que se refiera tanto a una pregunta como una respuesta.

Comment: Se refiere tanto a una pregunta como a una respuesta.

Comment: Pienso que debería cambiarse.