# Cómo sugerir mejoras a los artículos de la ayuda

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda

Actualmente existe [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones) dedicada a las mejoras en las traducciones aunque está enfocada principalmente a secciones en la interface de usuario de SO.es, sin embargo, yo estoy preguntando por la posibilidad de corregir párrafos o incluso artículos completos del centro de ayuda.

La inquietud nace al leer con detenimiento la guía ["Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable."](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), que acostumbro citar en los comentarios a los nuevos usuarios.

Este artículo tiene graves errores en su traducción, cito un claro ejemplo:

En el [original](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aparece en la sección *Minimal and readable*, la siguiente frase:

> Use consistent naming and indentation, and include comments if needed to explain portions of the code. *(Usa nombres y tabulaciones de forma consistente e incluye comentarios si necesitas explicar partes del código)*.

En el centro de ayuda, esa misma oración aparece de la siguiente manera:

> Usa **nombramientos** y **hendiduras** consistentes y no se te olvide incluir comentarios si necesitas explicar partes del código.

Adicionalmente de la mala elección de las traducciones, existen errores gramaticales y ortográficos a lo largo de todo el artículo.

Antes de dedicarle tiempo a la tarea, me gustaría conocer el mecanismo para la modificación (incluyendo las modificaciones sugeridas por preguntas de meta como [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/164#164), sobre la temática del sitio) de los artículos del centro de ayuda, toda vez que pueden afectar la conducta de la comunidad.

Comment: Yo también voy encontrando cosas pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer los cambios, proponerlos o qué hacer.

Comment: Cuando me encontré con esta situación, yo añadí una pregunta ([Errores ortográficos en “¿Que es ”meta“ y cómo funciona?”](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/575/83)) con las etiquetas [bug] y [documentación]. En muy poco rato Juan M lo modificó.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo que de momento la mejor opción es recopilar el máximo de errores o correciones y cuándo se tengan suficientes publicar un post en meta?

Answer (score 1):

Para sugerir mejoras a los artículos del centro de ayuda, simplemente repórtalo usando el Meta.  Revisaré las ediciones y haré los cambios en cuanto reciba la notificación.

@fedorqui escribió un buen comentario a la pregunta original.  Lo que sugiere el funciona de buena manera.

¡Gracias por el deseo de mejorar los artículos!