# Las explicaciones de votos en la etiqueta "reputación" son poco descriptivas, cambiémolas a "voto a favor/en contra" y "votar en contra"

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Me parecen algo raras las traducciones que actualmente hay en la pestaña [*reputación*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation) para definir los cambios en la reputación de cada cual.

Aquí vemos votos positivos que he recibido (+5 y +10), así como unos negativos que he hecho a respuestas (-1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí vemos dos votos negativos que recibí (-2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para mí, estas traducciones no reflejan claramente lo que está pasando y deberían mejorarse.**

Actualmente está así (originalmente ya es bastante lioso en inglés):

- *upvote* (recibir un voto positivo) → traducido como *votar a favor*.
- *downvote* (recibir un voto negativo) → traducido como  *votar en contra*.
- *downvoted* (votar negativamente una respuesta)  → traducido como *con votos en contra*.

Apuesto por un enfoque diferente en el que se distinga entre:

- acción de emitir votos: *votar*, como verbo.
- acción de recibir votos: *voto*, como sustantivo, o *votado* como participio.

De esta forma, lo dejaría en:

- *upvote* → ***voto a favor*** o ***votado a favor*** (recibir un +1).
- *downvote* → ***voto en contra*** o ***votado en contra*** (recibir un -1).
- *downvoted* → ***votar en contra*** (hacer un -1).

<sub>Conozco la pregunta [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/83). Publico una pregunta diferente en lugar de plantearlo como respuesta porque considero que es un tema no trivial que puede obtener mayor consenso y posibilidad de debate en este formato.</sub>

Comment: +1. Me falta una flecha dibujada a mano, eso si =P.

Comment: Creo que es lo mismo... Es como el motivo por el que se obtuvo el puntaje... +1 por: votar a favor.

Comment: @ArtEze convendrás conmigo que el actual _con votos en contra_ es un poco [WTF](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17948/1674): ni explica ni aclara.

Comment: No está del todo bien, pero si uno hace el esfuerzo se entiende. **-2 hace 11 horas eliminado**, significa que una edición sugerida se perdió por haber eliminado la pregunta. **+1 17:14 eliminado** significa que un voto en contra se revirtió por haberla eliminado.

Comment: @ArtEze creo que en tu último comentario te refieres a descripciones distintas de las que yo digo en la pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui: Creo que lo tienes al revés con los términos *downvote* y *downvoted*. *downvote* es la acción de emitir un voto, o sea *votar en contra*. Y *downvoted* es el estado de haber recibido un voto, o sea *voto en contra* o *votado en contra*.

Comment: @sstan no. Yo también dudé mientras redactaba la pregunta (de ahí que dijera _originalmente ya es bastante lioso en inglés_). Mira esta imagen de mi perfil en [so]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fd3m.png. Sale _downvoted_ cuando yo voté negativamente y _downvote_ cuando recibí un voto negativo.

Comment: @fedorqui: ya veo, tienes razón. Los términos pueden tener un sentido u otro dependiendo de si se trata de la perspectiva del que emite or recibe el voto. Me pregunto si valdría la pena incluir los términos *emitido* y *recibido* en la traducción para que eso quede claro (*recibido voto a favor*, *recibido voto en contra*, *emitido voto en contra*). Eso es lo que le falta en inglés también para que quede mas claro (*received upvote*, *received downvote*, *cast downvote*).

Comment: @sstan ¡me parece una idea muy buena! _Recibido voto a favor_ y _emitido voto en contra_ no dejan margen de duda.

Comment: Cualquiera sea la acepción elegida, creo que se debería utilizar un criterio uniforme, incluyendo a: [revocar el voto a favor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSxxA.png), [aceptar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4EiR.png), [dejar de aceptar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogsKD.png), [editar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt8yy.png), [eliminado (publicación con -1 o propia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErJIr.png), [eliminado (usuario)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n942H.png), [recompensa (ofrecida)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbBda.png), y [recompensa (recibida)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd9Yj.png)