# Reemplazar endiduras por sangrado o por indentación en artículo de ayuda mcve

Tags: discusión

> Esta pregunta no es un duplicado de [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83) ya que esta es sobre un caso específico y aquella al contrario, es sobre muchos, además, debido a los comentarios, se ha cambiado la etiqueta obligatoria a discusión.

Además:

1. Aquella es una pregunta del tipo "basada en opiniones", en el sentido que habrá muchas respuestas y ninguna será mas correcta que otra, que si bien son aceptables en Meta, el modelo no es apropiado para discusiones extensas.
2. La otra pregunta actualmente tiene 27 respuestas; está a sólo 3 de empezar a mostar un aviso como el que ya se muestra en [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/) en el que se indica que el hilo ya tiene 30 respuestas, como se [reportó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1474/65) el 25 de febrero.
3. Fue publicada a inicios de la beta pública, cuando el número de usuarios y publicaciones en Meta eran muy pocos.

---

En inglés dice

> Use consistent naming and indentation, and include comments if needed to explain portions of the code.

En español actualmente dice

> Usa nombramientos y hendiduras consistentes y no se te olvide incluir comentarios si necesitas explicar partes del código.

Hendiduras definitivamente es incorrecto. ¿Por cual término debería sustituirse?

Por ejemplo, podría usarse uno de los siguientes términos

- [Indentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n)
- [Sangrado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCj54xx)

Favor de publicar como respuesta su recomendación de traducción.

Comment: No estoy seguro que la palabra *sangrado* defina exactamente lo que deseas transmitir, propondría poner únicamente "*Usa nomenclatura e indentación de forma...*". La palabra *identación* como tal no existe en el diccionario de la RAE, pero para fines de [es.so], me parece que es un término completamente conocido y aceptado dentro del ámbito del desarrollo de software.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta debe ir en esta otra: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones que es el hilo oficial y está monitoreada permanentemente... de otra manera nos llenaríamos de preguntas pidiendo correcciones.

Comment: @Flxtr: He cambiado la etiqueta de soporte a discusión. Por favor agrega tu traducción como respuesta, mas tarde yo haré lo propio sobre sangrado, ya que este es el término correcto. Indentación es un anglicismo como se explica en las referencias que incluí.

Comment: @toledano: He cambiado la etiqueta de soporte a discusión por lo que se menciona en [el primer comentario](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555/reemplazar-endiduras-por-sangrado-en-art%c3%adculo-de-ayuda-mcve#comment4338_1555). También he incluído algunos comentarios sobre el hilo al que refieres.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave como indica Mariano, al menos al momento de que se publicó no había ninguna respuesta con la misma sugerencia y en todo caso, en lugar de marcar como duplicado hay otras formas mejores de hacer la integración en aquella pregunta. Considerando que en meta no se gana reputación, no debería haber reparo en que "alguien" tomara lo aquí propuesta y lo pusiera "allá", sin embargo, he como mencioné en un comentario previo he cambiado la etiqueta a discusión.

Comment: @Mariano: He editado la pregunta. ¿Qué opinas?

Comment: No hay que llenarnos de discusiones bizantinas, con los javeros ya hay mas que suficientes. Esto es una sugerencia de mejora y va en el hilo de sugerencias. Si la aceptan chido y si no, pues también chido.

Comment: @Rubén no se podría agregar una respuesta debido a que está marcada como duplicada, talvés sería mejor transladar el hilo de respuestas/sugerencias a la pregunta principal.

Answer (score 1):

Usar ambas, dado que sangrado es el término que se encuentra en el diccionario de la RAE, pero indentación es de uso común; asumo que muchos usuarios de SOes lo usan.

> Usa nomenclatura y sangrado (indentación) de forma consistente y no se te olvide incluir comentarios si necesitas explicar partes del código.

Comment: Me gusta esta traducción, los usuarios familiarizados con alguno de los términos podrán fácilmente entender a qué se refiere este punto. _En caso de que alguien tenga dudas_, siempre podrá consultar el diccionario.