# Eliminemos las peticiones de traducción que ya están completadas

Tags: discusión, traducciones, meta

Tenemos dos hilos de traducciones: [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones) y [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/7176).

Son hilos que se están haciendo bastante grandes y empieza a ser complicado encontrar cosas en ellos y ver qué es lo realmente falta por traducir o mejorar y algunas quedan relegadas al final de la lista para siempre, puede que algunas lo merezcan pero seguro que no todas.

Creo que sería bueno limpiar esos hilos un poco eliminado las traducciones que ya llevan algún tiempo marcadas como [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado).

Si no hay alguna razón para mantener todas esas propuestas de traducción creo que lo mejor sería quitarlas de en medio y dejar sitio a nuevas propuestas.

Comment: Tuve que crear la encuesta, en lo personal apoyo la propuesta para ir depurando esas publicaciones. Con esto sabremos qué es lo que opina la comunidad en general, además de no dejar una propuesta al aire. Si de plano vemos que no recibe la suficiente atención podremos determinar que no es lo que la comunidad desea ;)

Comment: Quizás sería bueno poner una respuesta, con todas las que ya están completadas, y dejar sueltas las demás, o dos respuestas wiki, una para las completadas y otra para las que no.

Comment: ¿En qué momento se supone que se puede decir que hay un consenso suficiente para poner en práctica una sugerencia de este tipo? Tal y como está ahora no creo que sea suficiente. Por otra parte hay dos votos en contra pero no se explican las razones. También un voto negativo en la respuesta del sí, lo cual falsea el resultado (aunque solo es un voto y no cambia mucho la cosa)

Comment: @blonfu Me parece que primero debe quedar claro quién se va a hacer cargo de eliminar las publicaciones en cuestión.

Comment: [lois6b lo acaba de hacer](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2889/eliminemos-las-peticiones-de-traducci%C3%B3n-que-ya-est%C3%A1n-completadas/2895?noredirect=1#comment11021_2895) :)

Answer (score 7):

## **Sí, eliminemos las peticiones de traducción que ya están completadas**

---

Estoy de acuerdo en depurar los hilos de la mejora de traducciones y los textos que no han sido traducidos.

Comment: Me parece bien. Nótese que eliminar no quiere decir eliminar del todo, pues los usuarios con más de 10.000 puntos de reputación seguirán viéndolo.

Comment: @fedorqui claro, totalmente de acuerdo. El entendido de *eliminar* es básicamente limpiar esas publicaciones para dejar lugar a aquellas que siguen pendientes :)

Comment: A esta propuesta le falta incluir la operacionalización de la misma. ¿Quien las borra? ¿El autor? Votar para eliminar sólo lo pueden hacer usuarios +10K que son muy pocos y menos aún los que colaboran en el tema de las traducciones. ¿Reportar para que las eliminen los mods ♦? ¿Qué opinan ellos?

Comment: @fedorqui creo que ya. dejé las *status by desing*. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

## **No, no eliminemos las peticiones de traducción que ya están completadas**

---

No estoy de acuerdo en depurar los hilos de la mejora de traducciones y los textos que no han sido traducidos.

Comment: Me gustaría saber las razones para elegir que no se eliminen ya que a mi no se me ocurre ninguna. También puede ayudar a algunos usuarios tomar una decisión sobre que opción elegir.