# ¿Qué hacemos con los hilos de lista de cosas sobre traducciones?

Tags: discusión, traducciones, meta

## Tl;Dr

Favor de votar en las respuestas a esta pregunta por mantener abiertos o cerrar

- [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65)
- [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/65)

## Explicación

Abro la discusión debido a que ya se había abordado esto en el pasado en uno de los hilos en cuestión -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1474/65, pero sólo se recibió un comentario, un voto positivo y un voto negativo y ahora que se retoma el tema de traducciones por diversas situaciones me parece relevante "reflotar" el tema.

Tenemos los hilos sobre traducciones referidos arriba que se crearon en los primeros días del lanzamiento del sitio. En su momento pareció una buena idea que fuera hilos del tipo de lista de cosas, lo cual se permite sólo en casos muy particulares.

Esta listas de cosas son de un tipo en particular, lista de tareas / situaciones por resolver, específicamente cosas pendientes de traducir y mejoras de traducción que una vez realizadas se les agregaba la etiqueta [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) y desde hace un año aproximadamente [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado).

Sin embargo hoy día resulta complicado estar buscando cosas que en esas listas y navegarlas resulta engorrísimo pues una tiene **80** y la otra **58** respuestas. Por otro lado, el buscador no  facilita mucho las cosas, ya que el operador lógico `or` sólo funciona para etiquetas. Ref. [Cómo buscar respuestas con la etiqueta [estado-completado]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3136/65).

Por otro lado, desde su publicación inicial a la fecha han pasado muchos cosas.

Hoy sabemos que

- hay un bug que hace que cosas ya traducidas se muestren en inglés y vuelvan a mostrarse en español
- cambios en la redacción en inglés realizado en el código crea una nueva cadena que hay que "volver" a traducir.

Así que les pido propuestas pero no más de 20 ¡por favor! (o bien votar por las dos alternativas que recién he agregado)

Aquí de nuevo los hilos en cuestión

- [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65)
- [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/65)

---

Acerca de los votos en Meta y en este hilo en particular

Vota positivo a esta pregunta si la encuentras útil/clara y negativo si no es así. Generalmente se vota en la preguntas [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva) para señalar acuerdo/desacuerdo pero en el resto de las preguntas debería votarse en cuanto a su utilidad/claridad. Referencia [¿Qué s Meta y cómo funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Hay dos respuestas señaladas como [Alternativa 1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3134/65) y [Alternativa 2](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3135/65). Vota positivo en la alternativa que te parezca mejor, con la que estás de acuerdo. Al menos en estas respuestas **No votes negativo**. Esto con la finalidad de facilitar el identificar cual de las alternativas se está de acuerdo ya que se requiere 1000 rep para ver el recuento de votos.

Answer (score 2):

## De momento, nada

De la lectura del chat completo [Grupo de Traducción - La charla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3071/83) (esto es, de lo hablado en [Hablemos sobre las traducciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/hablemos-sobre-las-traducciones)), así como de conversaciones con g3rv4 y demás, se deduce que estamos en pleno rediseño del tema de las traducciones. Ignoro si caeremos en el *gatopardismo* (cambiarlo todo para que no cambie nada :P), pero la cuestión es que se está redefiniendo la forma de proceder.

Esta nueva forma seguramente dependerá bastante de g3rv4 y su disponibilidad de seguir las publicaciones de Meta, así como de la evolución de su herramienta para gestionar las traducciones.

Por todo ello, creo que la decisión sobre qué debería hacerse al respecto debería ir sincronizada con la más importante: ¿qué le irá mejor a g3rv4 y al software que está desarrollando?

---

Ahora que la [Eliminemos las peticiones de traducción que ya están completadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2889/83) se ha implementado ([¡gracias lois6b!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2889/eliminemos-las-peticiones-de-traducci%C3%B3n-que-ya-est%C3%A1n-completadas/2895?noredirect=1#comment11021_2895)), la tarea resultará mucho más fácil.

Comment: Sobre la primera parte, "De momento nada" suena a la Alternativa 1, en cuanto a g3rv4, según entiendo está enfocado a los bugs y cosas que sólo un dev puede ver que en primera instancia no tiene relación con las alternativas 1 y 2, sino más bien con [meta-tag:agregar-a-transifex].

Comment: Sobre la segunda parte, lo de la abordar la propuesta [Eliminemos las peticiones de traducción que ya están completadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2889/65) me parece que es realmente una variante de la alternativa 1.

Comment: En cualquier caso, la idea principal de mi respuesta es: sugiero esperar acontecimientos y no precipitar cosas que dependen de otras cosas que se están debatiendo actualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa 2

Cerrar los hilos y seguir las nuevas indicaciones sobre las traducciones.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa 1

Dejar los hilos abiertos y continuar agregando respuestas