# Cómo buscar respuestas con la etiqueta [estado-completado]

Tags: soporte, búsqueda

Estoy buscando respuestas a [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65) que tengan la etiqueta [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) de la siguiente forma

[inquestion:40 [estado-completado]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A40%20%5Bestado-completado%5D)

Pero devuelve 0 resultados.

¿Cómo debo hacer la búsqueda?

Answer (score 1):

La búsqueda de etiquetas sólo busca, eso, etiquetas aplicadas a preguntas no markdown de etiquetas en el cuerpo de las publicaciones.

En lugar de `[estado-completado]` usa `"estado-completado"`.

Nota: Algunas respuestas en lugar de tener [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) tienen [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) pero el operador `or` sólo soporta etiquetas

- [inquestion:40 "estado-completado"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A40+%22estado-completado%22) (para respuestas a [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65))
- [inquestion:83 "estado-completado"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A83+%22estado-completado%22) (para respuestas a [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/65))

## Anexo

Se propone usar estado-completado en respuestas creadas a partir de 2017 y status-completed para respuestas creadas hasta 2016, así las siguientes búsquedas resultan más efectivas

- [inquestion:40 "status-completed" created:..2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A40%20%22status-completed%22%20created%3A..2016) para respuestas creadas hasta 2016
- [inquestion:40 "estado-completado" created:2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A40+%22estado-completado%22+created%3A2017) para respuestas creadas desde 2017

Comment: También se podrían editar las respuestas que tienen "status-completed" y sustituirlo por "estado-completado". Al fin y al cabo, cuando reciban alguna edición perderán el color rojo.

Comment: @fedorqui Si eso también funcionaría. Me pregunto si habrá alguien que se anime a realizar la faena de editar +40 respuestas :)

Comment: Habrá que mostrarles medallas muy relucientes para animarles :)