# Redacción de la explicación de Este es un comentario del tipo “yo también tengo el mismo problema”

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Llevo ya tiempo viendo esta opción entre las disponibles de *Eliminación Recomendada* en la cola de Publicaciones de Baja Calidad y siempre dudo al pulsarla, ya que aunque el encabezado es claro (*Este es un comentario del tipo “yo también tengo el mismo problema”*), la descripción no lo es en mi opinión. La descripción es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> “Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en Formular una pregunta. También puedes ofrecer una recompensa para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente reputación.”

La parte concretamente que me *chirría* es *Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en Formular una pregunta*. Si el post que se está marcando es un comentario se refiere a que tiene el mismo problema expuesto en esa pregunta, porqué se le dice *Si tienes una pregunta diferente ...*? Tal vez sea yo que no termino de entenderlo bien.

Yo propondría que el texto fuera algo así como

> "Si no existen respuestas, o las respuestas existentes no resuelven tu problema, puedes intentar Formular una nueva pregunta. También puedes ofrecer una recompensa para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente reputación."

o algo por el estilo.

¿Que pensáis vosotros? ¿Soy solo yo al que le suena mal?

P.D. Otra pregunta para redundar en el tema...Tal como está redactada ahora mismo...¿qué diferencia existe entre esa opción y la siguiente?

> “Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón Formular una pregunta. Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto.”

en cuanto al comentario que va a ver el autor de la respuesta?

Comment: ¿No había una opción que decia lo mismo que la captura en inglés que has puesto?: _"Esta respuesta debería ser una edición de la pregunta"_ o algo similar. No lo encuentro ahora pero estaba convencido de que existía

Comment: @blonfu cierto,es un fallo mío al coger el ejemplo del Stack Overflow. Ese texto depende de si la respuesta la ha añadido el OP u otra persona. Ahora lo edito

Comment: ah vale, por eso no lo encontraba ;)

Comment: @blonfu en inglés el texto es el mismo que en español, ha sido un fallo mio al no darme cuenta de que el coincidian el OP con el que respondía. En inglés dice: _This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
“This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question.”_

Comment: Relacionado: [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/65)

Comment: @Ruben no se si está relacionado. En realidad, si te fijas en el texto en inglés, la traducción es buena. Es más bien la redacción del texto (tanto en inglés como en español) de lo que trata mi pregunta.