# ¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso

Tags: discusión, traducciones, transifex

Si te interesa ayudar con una traducción y encontraste un término en inglés en el sitio, este es el proceso que vamos a seguir.

Verás que usamos el sistema de Transifex para almacenar y editar las cadenas del sitio. Por encima de ello, [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) creó [traducir.win](https://traducir.win), cuyo funcionamiento explicó en [Traduciendo el sitio… Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/83).

Es importante saber que no todas las cadenas y textos se encuentran allí. Existen algunas que tenemos que importar.

- ¿Aparece la cadena en traducir.win?

  - No → [Reporta en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=bug%20agregar-a-transifex) con las etiquetas [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) y [agregar-a-transifex](/questions/tagged/agregar-a-transifex)
  - Sí → Tradúcela y guarda la sugerencia.

Si el texto que aparece corresponde al [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), consulta lo descrito en [¿Cómo puedo sugerir un arreglo a una traducción en el Centro de Ayuda?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/83)

Comment: @Juan M Una consulta como le ponemos el titulo de la pregunta cuando la reportemos en Meta?

Comment: Gracias @JuanM, ahora si está claro el proceso

Comment: Se mencionan etiquetas a usar pero no las etiquetas obligatorias ¿Cuál etiqueta obligatoria se debería utilizar en cada caso? ¿[meta-tag:discusión],[meta-tag:soporte],[meta-tag:bug] ó [meta-tag:característica-nueva]? (por favor ser claros que se use sólo una y no combinaciones de etiquetas obligatorias)

Comment: @RaulCacacho El titulo a la pregunta puede ser la que gusten.  Lo que vamos a usar para encontrar estas peticiones son las etiquetas. Si el titulo es pertinente, no tengo problema con el uso de algo no estandarizado.

Comment: @Rubén usemos la de [bug](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) por ahora que en realidad es a lo que esto se reduce para nosotros.

Comment: @JuanM Muchas gracias por la información