# Al editar una pregunta, el texto explicativo aparece en inglés

Tags: bug, traducciones

Hace unos días me fijé en que, a la hora de editar una pregunta (o sugerir una edición para que sea revisada), el texto explicativo está a medio traducir, por así decirlo. La frase inicial, que especifica que la edición debe ser revisada, está en español, pero la explicación de lo que sería la edición (o consejo) aparece en inglés:

> Tu edición se colocará en una cola hasta que sea revisada por pares.
>
> We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more
>   valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please
>   try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for
>   example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and
>   hyperlinks.

Creo que pasa bastante desapercibido dado que la primera frase está en español.

Comment: [La cadena ya está traducida](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=We%20welcome). Recomiendo leer [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3166/83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acabo de traducirla en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/13558):

> Las ediciones que hacen que la publicación sea más fácil de entender y más valiosa para los lectores son bienvenidas. Debido a que los miembros de la comunidad revisan las ediciones, intenta que la publicación sea sustancialmente mejor que la forma en que la encontraste, por ejemplo, corrigiendo la gramática o agregando recursos e hipervínculos adicionales

En pocas horas debería aparecer traducida.

Aprovecho para recordaros que podéis ayudar a traducir el sitio entrando en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win), buscando la cadena sin traducción y realizando una sugerencia de como debería traducirse.

Comment: ¡Qué rápido! Lo mismo podríamos hacer una pregunta genérica para marcar todas estas preguntas como duplicadas. Si no, acabaremos con Meta desbordado de preguntas de este tipo cada vez que (como pasa recientemente) se cambian textos

Comment: ¡Qué velocidad! Que moderadores más eficientes tiene SOes :) Había leído ya varias veces lo de ayudar con las traducciones, debo ponerme y mirar la página de traducción para aprender a usarla, por si encuentro algo más y se os puede aliviar un poco la carga de trabajo :)

Comment: @fedorqui tal vez esta? ->https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/15301. Porque esta ->https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3166/15301 está basada en transifex. O te refieres a una nueva que explique mejor el proceso?

Comment: @fedorqui y por cierto...[estas sugerencias](https://traducir.win/string/5984)?

Comment: sobre estas sugerencias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/156493 me hizo ver que lo mismo se ve raro lo de _se aceptó_ para indicar si esa respuesta está aceptada o no

Comment: sobre las duplicadas, yo creo que la de Juan M es la estándar y podríamos apuntar allí, sí

Comment: @fedorqui ya veo...yal vez en la respuesta el texto debería ser "Aceptada" y en la pregunta "Aceptó"?...en ingles son "Is accepted" y "accepted" respectivamente...