# Explicación de "Basada en opiniones" sin traducir en cola de revisión

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

[Link de referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/203048).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3166/quieres-ayudar-a-traducir-las-cadenas-del-sitio-este-es-el-proceso)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muchas gracias por reportarlo. Ya está traducida de la siguiente manera (sujeta a vuestras sugerencias):

> Es probable que esta pregunta se responda con opiniones más que con hechos y citas. Debe ser actualizada para que conduzca a respuestas basadas en hechos.

Como bien te ha comentado @fedorqui, todos podemos ayudar a la traducción del sitio como se explica perfectamente en [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3166/quieres-ayudar-a-traducir-las-cadenas-del-sitio-este-es-el-proceso)

Comment: Genial!! ya agregué la pregunta sugerida a mis favoritos para la próxima traducción. Saludos