# Hace Falta Traducir dos textos en la Interface de Re-Apertura de Preguntas

Tags: soporte, traducciones

Hace Falta Traducir dos textos en la Interface de Re-Apertura de Preguntas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna forma de encontrar esto directamente en la herramienta de traducción y apoyar con la traducción??

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3166/quieres-ayudar-a-traducir-las-cadenas-del-sitio-este-es-el-proceso)

Comment: @padaleiana no lo responde, lo que quiero saber es como buscar en la herramienta para hacer la traducción, leíste la pregunta al final del post?? ***Existe alguna forma de encontrar esto directamente en la herramienta de traducción y apoyar con la traducción??*** y ya me dieron respuesta. saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar [es.traducir.win](http://es.traducir.win) para sugerir las ediciones que faltan, y asi alguien mas las apruebe.

en el caso de esa, el link seria este - https://es.traducir.win/strings/17909

---

Para la frase exacta, usa `Source Regex``y copia/pega la oración en inglés

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero como hiciste la búsqueda es lo que pregunto realmente ...