# Alerta muestra texto no decodificado al hacer clic a botón "¡Esto resolvió mi problema!"

Tags: bug, traducciones

Al hacer clic al botón ¡Esto resolvió mi problema! en una pregunta que fue votada para cerrar como duplicado de otra, se muestra una alerta con el siguiente téxto:

`Esto marcar&#225; tu pregunta como un duplicado, lo que redirigir&#225; a futuros lectores hacia la pregunta original y evitar&#225; que se publiquen futuras respuestas aqu&#237;.`

Nótese que:

- `&#225;` es á
- `&#237;` es í

Debería mostrarse de la siguiente forma

> Esto marcará tu pregunta como un duplicado, lo que redirigirá a futuros lectores hacia la pregunta original y evitará que se publiquen futuras respuestas aquí.

<sub>Nota: El problema es que que las alertas usan texto plano y no HTML. <strike>Seguramente esto se debe a un cambio en la forma en la que se muestra el aviso al usuario</strike>.</sub>

Esta cadena si está en Transifex / traducir.win

---

Reportado en MSE

[International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts / email subject on Stack Overflow en español are shown as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/289691)

---

Para validar que se ha corregido, fedorqui amablemente ha marcado como duplicada.

En lugar de la alerta con el problema, ahora se muestra un aviso en azul directamente en la página de la pregunta, al seleccionar Sí y hacer clic en enviar se muestra el aviso siguiente:

[image]

Comment: Esto ya lo había reportado en [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1863/127)

Comment: Lo mismo que con el mensaje al intentar retirarse de las elecciones primarias ([reporte de ArtEze](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2547/83))

Comment: @Mariano ¡Que buena memoria!

Comment: Voto para cerrar para que puedas validar si se ve bien ahora, en cuanto puedas revisar retiro el voto :)

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias. Actualicé la pregunta

Comment: Por cierto, favor de votar para reabrir :)

Comment: Qué bien! Acabo de hacerlo. El mensaje para reabrir también está en inglés. Lo copié en el móvil, mañana lo busco en traducir.win para traducirlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo indicado en [la respuesta de m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341739/209901) de hoy mismo esto a la pregunta de Meta.SE [International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts / email subject on Stack Overflow en español are shown as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/209901), esto ha sido corregido.