# Mala codificación al ir a marcar como duplicada una pregunta propia

Tags: bug

Al ir a marcar una pregunta propia como duplicada, aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver, no está codificando bien los acentos. Supongo que pasará lo mismo con las ñ y caracteres especiales.

¿Se podría corregir?

Comment: jajaj... Esto lo reporté hace 1 año en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1863/127 y Rubén ya incluso lo duplicó en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3287/127 ... Mi conclusión hasta ahora es que este caso específico (junto a otros que muestran las entidades codificadas que habría que juntar en una única publicación) es que convendría reportarlo en MSE... En SOes se le está dando más prioridad a otros pedidos, principalmente el de arreglar el problema de Transifex.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano, estuve buscando algo parecido por aquí pero no he encontrado nada :'(. Ahora la marco como duplicada de la de Rubén.