# Completar registro en Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

El correo de confirmación de dirección de correo electrónico al momento de registrarse como nuevo usuario dice

`Completar registro en Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol`

en lugar de

Completar registro en Stack Overflow en español

Cliente de correo usado Inbox by Gmail
Navegador Chrome para Windows: Versión 65.0.3325.181 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Relacionado

- [Alerta muestra texto no decodificado al hacer clic a botón "¡Esto resolvió mi problema!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3287/65)

Reportado en MSE

[International characters used on prompts / email subject are shown as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/289691)

Comment: le saqué la tag [meta-tag:agregar-a-transifex] porque [ya está en transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/$?q=key%3A4a32165bbea19dc800d59a09a9f0c7c8) ;)

Comment: Ups. Se me pasó dejar el nombre del sitio como variable :)

Comment: Hice [esta búsqueda](https://traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%5ECompletar%20registro%20en) para encontrarla

Comment: Recién me doy cuenta que había hecho esta otra [completar el registro](https://traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=Completar%20el%20registro)

Comment: @Rubén ¿sigue sucediendo esto?

Comment: @JuanM: Recién acabo de hacer un nuevo registro y pasó exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Acabo de ver que en la página de confirmación de nombre está "Send me occasional Stack Overflow news, product updates and more." Ya envié la sugerencia de traducción en traducir.win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo indicado en [la respuesta de m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341739/209901) de hoy mismo esto a la pregunta de Meta.SE [International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts / email subject on Stack Overflow en español are shown as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/209901), esto ha sido corregido.