# Error con caracteres especiales en el mini perfil del usuario

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, perfil

Cuando posicionas el mouse sobre la información del mini perfil del usuario aparece el la información:

`puntuaci&#243;n de reputaci&#243;n`

no renderiza la letra "ó" sino muestra el código HTML `"&#243;"`

[image: Ejemplo de error]

Comment: Parecido a [Completar registro en Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3407/83)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Va a quedar solucionado en la próxima versión (hoy). Teníamos un string que era codificado en HTML, después como un string otra vez, y después, otra vez, en HTML. Ahora no cambia de ida y vuelta.